# Route state name in React+Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, redux

I have 2 routes using same component (form), one to create new entry and the other to edit. State name [has been removed](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/119) from React Router, I can't just check if this.route.name === 'edit' => fetch(itemAPI).

One option is to write reducer/action to create "edit" state in my redux store, but I was wondering if it's the best practice and if there is an easier way to check where I am in the app (which route).

My routes:

```
<Route component={ItemNew} path='/items/edit/:id' />
<Route component={ItemNew} path='/items/new' />
```

In my ItemNew component, I'd like to:

```
componentDidMount () {
    let stateName = this.props.location.state
    if(stateName === 'edit') {
        this.props.fetchItem() // dispatch API action
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Route` component used to perform the final part of the match on the current URL shows up on `this.props.route`; the entire list of nested `Route`s that participated in the match is in the `this.props.routes` array. You can pass any arbitrary props onto these `Route`s and retrieve them later. For example:

```
<Route component={ItemNew} name="edit" path='/items/edit/:id' />
<Route component={ItemNew} name="add" path='/items/new' />
```

and

```
componentDidMount () {
  if(this.props.route.name === 'edit') {
    this.props.fetchItem() //dispatch API action
  }
}
```

Comment: @alexndm Not by default. Either push it into the state using a hook (like `onEnter` or `componentDidMount`), or look into something like [redux-simple-router](https://github.com/rackt/redux-simple-router) or [redux-router](https://github.com/acdlite/redux-router)